# win10 app: extend file browser

Tags: javascript, file, winjs, windows-10, file-browser

I'd want to extend win10 file browser by supporting tags and maybe other future features.

the doc explains how to read files:
[msdn.microsoft.com: files folders and libs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185399.aspx)

I wonder if there is way to get an object representing the file browser? in order to not recode it entirely

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the docs you link you are writing a Windows Runtime app, the FilePicker is not extensible.

Since the pickers are primary interfaces to the file broker they can't be implemented in user code. The app could draw a fancy UI but wouldn't have access to underlying files (unless previously granted by a file picker equivalent)